# What is the redirect_uri?

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-login

I'm trying to authenticate facebook users into a web-app i'm building without the javascript SDK, I'm following [This guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/). In the first step (where I'm supposed to send the appId along with the redirect_uri),

I have the redirect_uri set to "http%3A%2F%2Feduudle.com%2Fborhom2", it works as expected and sends the code parameter to the backend.

However, in the second step where I'm supposed to send the code along with the client_secret and the redirect_uri, I send the same redirect_uri and it doesn't work. I get the following message "Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request"

I have tried the slash at the end, replacing the : with %3A and the / with %2F. I'm 100% sure that the redirect_uri is EXACTLY the same as the one I'm sending in the get request.

The only case where I'd be wrong is if I misunderstood what the redirect_uri is and how to change it from facebook. Try it yourself "http:// eduudle.com / borhom"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm 100% sure that the redirect_uri is EXACTLY the same as the one I'm sending in the get request.

Doesn’t look like that.

Clicking login on your sample page redirects me to

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=461627793920081&
  redirect_uri=http://eduudle.com/borhom2&scope=…
```

whereas the Graph URL giving the error afterwards is like this,

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?code=…&client_secret=…&
  redirect_uri=http://eduudle.com/&client_id=461627793920081#_=_
```

So check your code for the part where that URL is generated and redirected to – I’m pretty sure its your mistake ;-(